# sample a different number of random rows for each level of a factor with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I an trying to take a random sample from each level of a factor.  There are a different number of observations for each factor level.  For each level I want to create a sample with half as many observations.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("AAA", "AAA","AAA","BBB","BBB","CCC"), length = 100),
                  Value = sample(1:100, replace = T))
```

Using the data above, it seems like something like the following should nearly work, but the error (*Error in n() : This function should not be called directly*) suggests I am incorrectly using the n() function.

```
Samp <- dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_n(size = n()/2 )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `sample_frac()`:

```
library(dplyr)
Samp <- dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_frac(.5)
```